Upon what does the half life of a nuclide depend on?
Nuclide half-lives seem to be apparently random, except for the fact that heavier elements are typically radioactive and lighter ones stable. Is there any factor that can predict the half life of a given nuclide (e.g. based on its position on the periodic table)?

This is task for the theoretical quantum physics of atomic nuclei. Btw it is matter of particular nuclides, not elements.  Most of elements have tens of known radioactive nuclides,  natural or man-made, each having its own half life.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/158100/neutron-proton-ratio-and-isotope-stability https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20146/what-makes-elements-radioactive

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134338/has-the-half-life-of-an-isotope-ever-been-accurately-predicted-before-it-could-b

As a qualitative rule of thumb, among radioactive elements, those with odd proton number ( e.g. in odd numbered groups in periodic table) often tend to be less stable with shorter half lives. See At, Fr, Ac, Pa.  Also nuclides with both proton and neutron numbers even are generally more stable than odd-even or even-odd nuclides, with the least stable generally with both numbers odd. E.g. nitrogen-14 is the heaviest stable odd-odd nuclide (except one metastable nuclide of Ta).
